# Why does Joel insist on looking for Rose and even breaking down the door?

Tags: plot-explanation, smile-2022

In [Smile](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15474916/), Joel knows how the curse works. But at the end of the movie, he still goes looking for Rose and despite Rose screaming No! repeatedly, he still breaks the door down (and so allows the curse to take place).

Why does he do this (incredibly stupid thing)? (Other than the filmmakers wanting to end the movie this way and perhaps also set up the possibility of a sequel.)